# Chrome Extension BackgroundScript Path

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I'm trying to load background script from cdn path (**'https://cdn.xyz.com/scripts/background.js'**) in manifest.json in my **Chrome Extension**, but it's throwing me error - **Could not load background script 'https://cdn.xyz.com/scripts/background.js'**. I have already added https://cdn.xyz.com in content_security_policy in manifest.json file.

Manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "MyExtension",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "https://cdn.xyz.com/scripts/background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": [
       "http://*/*",
       "https://*/*",
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://cdn.xyz.com; object-src 'self'"    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly add a remote script in a manifest.

Adjusting the CSP allows you to dynamically load the script - by creating a `<script>` node with appropriate `src` in your (local) background code.

```
// Local background script
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://cdn.xyz.com/scripts/background.js"; 
document.head.appendChild(script); // Executes in background document
```

Please do note that such code loading (most of the logic is hosted elsewhere and updates independently, executed in privileged context) is very frowned upon by Google and outright banned by Mozilla for listed WebExtensions.

Comment: Can I dynamically remove this injected script from background-scripts and inject some other js file on some event like chrome.tabs.onCreated ?

Comment: Define "remove". You can't undo execution effects (in general case).

Comment: By remove I mean to remove execution effects and all the event listeners and Can you tell me how to do that exactly

Comment: No. Because there is no general way to so so. You need to do it for your specific changes and listeners.

Answer (score 0):

That CDN uses `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` to redirect to `cdn.xyz`, try:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://cdn.xyz https://cdn.xyz.com; object-src 'self'"`
```

If it works, you could also add wildcard domains and keep the old `cdn.xyz.com` domain for backwards compatibility.

Comment: The old DNS redirects to the new one and it does not seem to be online from my side, can you run `curl -I -L https://cdn.xyz.com/scripts/background.js` ?